# Apache Vhost redirect domain then page

Tags: apache-2.2, rewrite

I trying to rewrite the domain then redirect to a new page afterwards.

So project1.com,www.project1.com, project2.co.nz and www.project2.co.nz end all redirect to the new domain http://newsite.com fine.

But I need project1.com/2012 to go to http://newsite.com/blog/archive ?

I've removed the **L** from the domain rewrite rule to allow it to evaluate the final rewrite rule ... but no joy?

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName project1.com
    ServerAlias www.project1.com project2.co.nz www.project2.co.nz

    Options +FollowSymlinks
    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}    !^newsite\.com [NC]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}    !^$
    RewriteRule ^/(.*)  http://newsite.com/$1 [R=301]

# project1.com/2012 needs to go to -> http://newsite.com/blog/archive
    RewriteRule ^(2012)$ https://newsite.com/blog/archive [R=301]
</VirtualHost>
```

If anyone can help it'd be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Put the 'special' rule first -- and you probably want the `RewriteCond` for both.  Also - do you actually need to account for clients that don't send a `Host` header?

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^newsite\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^/2012$ https://newsite.com/blog/archive [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^newsite\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^/(.*)$  http://newsite.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```